# Http Post with Blackberry 6.0 issue

Tags: json, blackberry, post, http-post

I am trying to post some data to our webservice(written in c#) and get the response. The response is in JSON format.

I am using the Blackberry Code Sample which is BlockingSenderDestination Sample. When I request a page it returns with no problem. But when I send my data to our webservice it does not return anything.

The code part that I added is :

```
ByteMessage myMsg = bsd.createByteMessage();
//myMsg.setStringPayload("I love my BlackBerry device!");
myMsg.setMessageProperty("querytpe","myspecialkey");//here is my post data
myMsg.setMessageProperty("uname","myusername");
myMsg.setMessageProperty("pass","password");
((HttpMessage) myMsg).setMethod(HttpMessage.POST);
// Send message and wait for response myMsg
response = bsd.sendReceive(myMsg);
```

What am i doing wrong? And what is the alternatives or more efficients way to do Post with Blackberry.

Regards.

Here is my whole code:

```
class BlockingSenderSample extends MainScreen implements FieldChangeListener {

ButtonField _btnBlock = new ButtonField(Field.FIELD_HCENTER);
private static UiApplication _app = UiApplication.getUiApplication();
private String _result;
public BlockingSenderSample()
{
    _btnBlock.setChangeListener(this);
    _btnBlock.setLabel("Fetch page");
    add(_btnBlock);
}

public void fieldChanged(Field button, int unused)
{

    if(button == _btnBlock)
    {

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run()
            {
                Message response = null;
                String uriStr = "http://192.168.1.250/mobileServiceOrjinal.aspx"; //our webservice address
                //String uriStr = "http://www.blackberry.com";

                BlockingSenderDestination bsd = null;
                try
                {
                    bsd = (BlockingSenderDestination)
                               DestinationFactory.getSenderDestination
                                   ("name", URI.create(uriStr));//name for context is name. is it true?
                    if(bsd == null)
                    {
                        bsd =
                          DestinationFactory.createBlockingSenderDestination
                              (new Context("ender"),
                               URI.create(uriStr)
                               );
                    }
                    //Dialog.inform( "1" );
                    ByteMessage myMsg = bsd.createByteMessage();
                    //myMsg.setStringPayload("I love my BlackBerry device!");
                    myMsg.setMessageProperty("querytpe","myspecialkey");//here is my post data
                    myMsg.setMessageProperty("uname","myusername");
                    myMsg.setMessageProperty("pass","password");
                    ((HttpMessage) myMsg).setMethod(HttpMessage.POST);

                    // Send message and wait for response myMsg
                    response = bsd.sendReceive(myMsg);

                    if(response != null)
                    {   
                        BSDResponse(response);
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    //Dialog.inform( "ex" );
                    // process the error
                }
                finally
                {
                    if(bsd != null)
                    {
                        bsd.release();
                    }
                }
            }

        });
        t.start();

    }
}

private void BSDResponse(Message msg)
{
    if (msg instanceof ByteMessage)
    {
        ByteMessage reply = (ByteMessage) msg;
        _result = (String) reply.getStringPayload();
    } else if(msg instanceof StreamMessage)
    {
        StreamMessage reply = (StreamMessage) msg;
        InputStream is = reply.getStreamPayload();
        byte[] data = null;
        try {
            data = net.rim.device.api.io.IOUtilities.streamToBytes(is);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // process the error
        }
        if(data != null)
        {
            _result = new String(data);
        }
    }

    _app.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            _app.pushScreen(new HTTPOutputScreen(_result));
        }

    });

}

}
```

..

```
class HTTPOutputScreen extends MainScreen 
{

RichTextField _rtfOutput = new RichTextField();

public HTTPOutputScreen(String message)
{
    _rtfOutput.setText("Retrieving data. Please wait...");
    add(_rtfOutput);
    showContents(message);
}

// After the data has been retrieved, display it
public void showContents(final String result) 
{
    UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() 
    {

        public void run() 
        {
            _rtfOutput.setText(result);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

HttpMessage does not extend ByteMessage so when you do:

```
((HttpMessage) myMsg).setMethod(HttpMessage.POST);
```

it throws a ClassCastException.  Here's a rough outline of what I would do instead.  Note that this is just example code, I'm ignoring exceptions and such.

```
//Note: the URL will need to be appended with appropriate connection settings
HttpConnection httpConn = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url);
httpConn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
OutputStream out = httpConn.openOutputStream();
out.write(<YOUR DATA HERE>);
out.flush();
out.close();

InputStream in = httpConn.openInputStream();
//Read in the input stream if you want to get the response from the server

if(httpConn.getResponseCode() != HttpConnection.OK)
{
    //Do error handling here.
}
```

Comment: The problem is what should i write in "out.write(MYDATA)" ? For example which format i should write my uname and value to write method so server can understand.

Comment: The answer to that question really depends on what format the server is expecting.  The output stream takes a byte array so you can write whatever data you want to it.  However, I suspect that you want to send URL encoded data in which case you should use the URLEncodedPostData class.  To get the byte array that the output stream is expecting use urlEncodedData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

Comment: as you said server send response in json so chances are there that server is also expecting request in Json ... give it try ...