# json parsing in blackberry?

Tags: json, blackberry

I am working on a web-service application using JSON.
In performing task I got success in directly fetching JSOn response by hitting the URL.

Now I have a task to request with a request parameter.

```
enter code here
private void callJSON_Webservice(String method,String paraLastModifiedDate) {
        HttpConnection c=null;
        InputStream is = null;
        String feedURL = Constants.feedURL;
        int rc;

        try{
            JSONObject postObject = new JSONObject();
            postObject.put("CheckLatestDataDate",method);
            postObject.put("LastModifiedDate", paraLastModifiedDate);
            //c = new HttpConnectionFactory().getHttpConnection(feedURL);
            c = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(feedURL + ConnectionManager.getConnectionString());

            // Set the request method and headers
            c.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
            c.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            c.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + (postObject.toString().length() - 2));
            //c.setRequestProperty("method", HttpConnection.GET);

            // Getting the response code will open the connection,
            // send the request, and read the HTTP response headers.
            // The headers are stored until requested.
            rc = c.getResponseCode();

            if (rc != HttpConnection.HTTP_OK){
                throw new IOException("HTTP response code: " + rc);
            }

            is = c.openInputStream();

            String json = StringUtils.convertStreamToString(is);
            object = new JSONObject(json);


        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e+"call webservice exception");
        }

    }
```

With this code I am getting EOF exception. I need to complete this small task as soon as possible. Please help me...!
Thanx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing

```java
is = c.openInputStream();

String json = StringUtils.convertStreamToString(is);
```

with following:

```java
is = c.openInputStream();

StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
int ch = 0;
while (ch != -1) {
    ch = is.read();
    buffer.append((char) ch);
}

String json = buffer.toString();
```

Reference: [convert StreamConnection to String](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/convert-StreamConnection-to-String/td-p/989825)

Comment: Rupak, I am very confused in sending REQUEST parameter in JSON and XML, I have already performed XML parsing by posting request parameter but not able to done it in JSON. Please provide some sample code or snippet to guide me, from the core.

Comment: Check these links, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380400/json-send-post-error-in-blackberry, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339656/send-json-request-from-blackberry-application, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531822/http-post-with-blackberry-6-0-issue, http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-to-POST-JSON/td-p/587757

Comment: thanz alot Rupak, this is really a great help...! I have done with the task. And got my data. The step of sending request to server is similar to that of xml parsing, just we need to take care of the response which we will get in form of JSON. set in my mind for entire life. Thanx alot to the community.